# Can an inputAccessoryView be used for actual input

Tags: ios, uitextfield

This morning I was looking over some old code I found somewhere (and used in an app) that hacks a `UIAlertView` in order to get one string of input from the user.  It's overkill for the purpose and looks rather silly but I've never seen a simpler way.  I then came up with the following approach, which **seems** to work (iPad 5.1.1 and simulator).

My question is a bit open-ended but, essentially, are there conditions under which this breaks as a strategy: create an off-screen text field with an accessory view, put a proxy text field in the accessory view, and forward various property settings to the proxy?

PMKeyboardTextField.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PMKeyboardTextField : UITextField
- (id)initWithPrompt:(NSString *)prompt;
@end
```

PMKeyboardTextField.m:

```
#import "PMKeyboardTextField.h"

@interface PMKeyboardTextField ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *inputField;
@end

@implementation PMKeyboardTextField
@synthesize inputField = _inputField;

- (id)initWithPrompt:(NSString *)prompt {
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, -1, 1, 1)];
    if (self) {
        UIView *accessory =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 72)];
        [accessory setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.8 alpha:0.8]];

        UILabel *getLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 284, 21)];
        [getLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        getLabel.text = prompt;
        [accessory addSubview:getLabel];

        self.inputField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 37, 264, 31)];
        [accessory addSubview:self.inputField];

        self.inputAccessoryView = accessory;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow {
    [self.inputField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (id<UITextFieldDelegate>)delegate {
    return self.inputField.delegate;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id<UITextFieldDelegate>)delegate {
    self.inputField.delegate = delegate;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I like this idea for its ability to avoid the excess clutter of an alert view or the need to reposition on-screen views, the fatal flaw was pointed out to me in another forum: some people use external keyboards!

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting iOS 5.0 or later, you don't need to hack the alert view to add a text field.  You can just set the alert view's `alertViewStyle` to `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` to give the alert view one plaintext input field, which you can then access by sending `textFieldAtIndex:` to the alert view.

Aside from that, your workaround seems ok.  I guess you have to add your offscreen text field to the alert view's window, not your normal app window.

Comment: Actually, this is intended to work in any view without creating an alert view.  (The actual use I have in mind is for when someone hits a '+' to add something to a table view and I'd like to have them name it as it's being created without putting an editable field into the table view cell...or putting up that otherwise unnecessary alert view.)

Comment: In that case I would just add the accessory bar as a regular subview at the bottom edge of your top-level view, send `becomeFirstResponder` to the text field in it, and slide it up based on `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.